# Vulnerabilities on Spring Boot Loader

Tags: spring-boot, security, vmware

in my project I have spring-boot 2.0.5 and spring-boot-loader-tool 2.0.5.
Some vulnerabilities are found and some of them are about vmware.

- CVE-2014-4199    CWE-59 Improper Link Resolution Before File Access
  ('Link
  Following')  Medium(6.3) spring-boot-loader-tools-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- CVE-2014-4200    CWE-264 Permissions, Privileges, and Access
  Controls Medium(4.7) spring-boot-loader-tools-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- CVE-2016-7079    CWE-476 NULL Pointer
  Dereference  Medium(4.6) spring-boot-loader-tools-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- CVE-2016-7080    CWE-476 NULL Pointer
  Dereference  Medium(4.6) spring-boot-loader-tools-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- CVE-2018-6969    CWE-125 Out-of-bounds
  Read Medium(4.4) spring-boot-loader-tools-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- CVE-2015-5191    CWE-362 Concurrent Execution using Shared Resource with
  Improper Synchronization ('Race
  Condition')  Low(3.7)    spring-boot-loader-tools-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- CVE-2016-5328    CWE-200 Information
  Exposure Low(2.1)    spring-boot-loader-tools-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar

It's not clear why spring boot loader use vmware,
can someone explain this vulnerabilities and how I can resolve them?

Comment: I doubt that those a properly detected and are valse positives.